# Scene remain on background after navigate to new file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, navigation, overlap

I cant stop the existing SWF after load another SWF. New SWF is run on top of the old SWF. I would like to know the simplest way to link all this up.

Scene 1
File 1: MainMenu.SWF (Consist of 2 Picture File)
- Subject1.JPG (Click and Load Subject1MainMenu.SWF)
- Subject2.JPG (Click and Load Subject2MainMenu.SWF)

Scene 2
File 2: Subject1MainMenu.SWF

Scene 3
File 3: Subject2MainMenu.SWF

Below is my code,

```
import flash.events.*;

var Subject1 = new Loader();
a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onMouseClick);

function onMouseClick (event:MouseEvent)
{
   subject1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
   Subject1.load(new URLRequest("Subject1MainMenu.SWF")); 
}

function onLoaderComplete(Event)
{
    var mainmenu = subject1;
    addChild(mainmenu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no one size fits all to all this.

1. You can hide your main menu swf while you load and show child swf
2. you can remove your main menu completely while you show your child swf and later in some other flow, you reload your main menu again
3. you can also use module manager to manage the swf loading and unloading